Renderer suddenly stopped working
System:
13th gen i5 intel
7900 xt 20gb vram
windows 11
ram 32 ddr5
Blender 4.1
I am using Cycles, scene is 1.8gb
I tried:

Changing to CPU, both, only GPU switching render devices
Changing samples
Changing tiles
Output folder

What I saw was that my GPU wasnt affected from starting the render it just the RAM that gets fully used up for the whole time the render window is open
I've read through every related sub I could find for the last 7 hours and still couldn't find a solution
Yesterday everything was working correctly then in the evening it started crashing while the renderer was denoising the image and now it not even starting
Edit:
I resolved the first part of the problem because there were to many particles so I deleted all, now Blender suddenly crashes after the renderer finishes right before the denoising would start. Also when I cancel the renderer with Esc Blender also crashes




How do you "render with none"? What does that mean? I think you should edit the question and explain in detail what happens, share screenshots with your render settings or even the .blend file.

@MartynasŽiemys I attached screenshots but dont know how to download the settings, hope this helps

It's difficult to give a definitive answer. If it starts rendering and crashes on denoising, consider disabling denoising and doing it after the render as a separate step using the Compositor. It would be better to render to EXR for this. If the GPU is not running out of memory(cannot see the VRAM usage in the gif) and still crashes, updating GPU drivers is always the thing to do. It happens that there are bugs in the drivers sometimes, so trying previous versions might sometimes also help.

If you still have particles, you might be ruining out of RAM as well, because there might be some operations intense on memory before sending the result to render to VRAM even if it fits VRAM for rendering and you have more RAM. Don't worry if Windows Task Manager does not report GPU usage, it's known to be wrong sometimes. Try other software for monitoring GPU usage.

I believe you might still be simply running out of memory. I would check that. 20GB VRAM is quite close to 32GB of RAM as well, and the OS and other software might use the 12GB... It's possible. I would try to rule that out for sure.
